# How do you find such points?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The following is the plot of [$y=4x^6+x^5+2x^3-x^4-5x-3$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D4x%5E6%2Bx%5E5%2B2x%5E3-x%5E4-5x-3)

[image]

There's a point in the red oval where the derivative changes "speed". Before that point the function quickly decreases and after that point the function decreases slowly. How do you find this point?

Comment: Isn't this a point where $y''$ is near maximal (so $y'''\approx0$)?

Comment: @Marconius I suspect that the third (or higher) derivative is zero at this point but didn't find any reference.

Comment: Plotting the [second](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D24x%5E5%2B5x%5E4%2B6x%5E2-4x%5E3-5), [third](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D120x%5E4%2B20x%5E3%2B12x-12x%5E2), [fourth](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D480x%5E3%2B60x%5E2%2B12-24x) and [fifth](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D1440x%5E2%2B120x-24) derivatives,  I couldn't find anything.

Comment: As the plot of the third derivative shows, $y''' = 0$ near $x=-0.6$.

Comment: @Théophile Yes but the point should be near $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may be thrown off by the scale of the picture. It's easier to see what's going on if you zoom in. Here's a plot of the function (red) as well as its first derivative (green). As you can see, the derivative has a local maximum at approximately $x=-0.6$, which is the point that meets your description:

> There's a point ... where the derivative changes "speed". Before that point the function quickly decreases and after that point the function decreases slowly.

[image]

Comment: I was going to study the osculating circles.

Comment: The curvature of the function achieves a local maximum at around $x=-0.75$.